# Inverse of $f(x)=x^2+2$ with restricted domain

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Of course, if $f(x)=x^2+2$, then $f^{-1}(x)=\pm\sqrt{x-2}$, where the sign of the root depends on whether or not your domain for $f$ is $x\geq0$ or $x\leq0$. If $x\geq0$, then $f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{x-2}$, and everything works out great.

If, however, we look at $x\leq0$, then $f^{-1}(x)=-\sqrt{x-2}$. Thus,

$f(f^{-1}(x))=f(-\sqrt{x-2})=(-\sqrt{x-2})^2+2=x$, where $x\geq2$, and

$f^{-1}(f(x))=f^{-1}(x^2+2)=-\sqrt{(x^2+2)-2}=-\sqrt{x^2}=-x$, where $x\leq0$

Where am I going wrong here? How can I get $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$? It seems like something very obvious, but I am not sure what I am missing. Clearly $x^2+2$, when defined on $x\leq0$, should have an inverse, and that should be $-\sqrt{x-2}$, but the above calculations do not seem to make much sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here $-\sqrt{x^2} = -|x| = x$, when $x \leq 0$.

Comment: Yes, this is what I thought, but I was stupid and did not apply the definition of absolute value for when $x\leq0$. So I just ended up with $-|x|$. Applying the definition makes all things end nicely. (Will accept once time limit disappears.)